# Drawing the curve y = 1 - x ^ 4 in Processing/Java

Tags: java, math, drawing, processing, exponent

I understand that `y = x ^ n` would be `float y = (x, n)`
but what if i wanted to draw the curves

```
y = 1 - x ^ 4
y = (1-x) ^ 4
y = 1-(1-x) ^ 4
```

Here's the code i wrote but it doesn't draw the curve mathematically correct for 
`y = 1 - x ^ 4`

```
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
  float n = norm(x, 0.0, 100.0);
  float y = pow(1-n, 4);
  y *= 100;
  smooth();
  point(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

you're making it draw (1-x)^4

you want to change `float y = pow(1-n, 4);` to `float y = 1-pow(n, 4);`